# where do the objects created in c# stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net

assume that i create an object

```
public UserDetails GetUserDetail(){
    UserDetails user=new UserDetails();
    user.Name=someFunctionThatReturnsName();
    user.BankAccountNumber=someInternalFunctionThatReturnsAccountNumberFromDB();
    return user;
}
```

When I create this object in code behind file, where exactly are these getting stored?
Are they stored in client side?  If yes can i modify these values?
Say if Facebook is storing details of logged in user in an object can I modify it using console or something in client side?

How is this handled when 100 people access a web application at the same time?
How objects are created and appropriately returned?

so whenever i create/access objects i am making a server hit?

Comment: At Server side. What we would get is the formatted result using them.

Comment: that object is created in memory and stored nowhere, at least not within the function you provided. So as soon as the reference to your UserDetails object is gone, so is your object and its data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot os possibilities. In the sample you provide, the objects are stored at the server side memory. For each single user, an object will be stored during the request live.

If you declare a [`static object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx), it will be stored at the server side memory but on the appDomain, I mean, a single instance will be shared with all users on the website.

### ASP.NET Objects

In the asp.net there are also a possibility to store objects in the [`Session`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx), [`ViewState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) and other objects that comes from asp.net plataform. I suggest you read more about them and use as you need it.

Depending of the context, you could store an generic dictionary of a custom objects and works with it on a single reference.

### Value Types vs Reference Types

Just to add, I think it is important you see something about, how [values types and reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) are stored, see how they work and how you should care of your objects. Basically:

- Reference types - on the heap
- Values type - on the stack memory

Comment: oh okay. As i create more objects (as more users access it), it will consume more server resources. So is it good to store things in cookies ?

Comment: Depende, cookies is good when you need to recovery some data in another access. Anyway, it will be recovery from cookie and stored in the server-side memory to be used.

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in memory on the server. in simple terms the worker thread on the server allocates the memory. When 100 people access the site, 100 objects are allocated in memory. Once these objects go out of scope they die (or at least they are garbage collected).

Comment: so whenever i create/access objects i am making a server hit?

Comment: if the code is on the server, you've already made the server hit. One request could create many objects (the page itself is just and object).